# Task.WhenAll for grabbing data from a web service

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, maui

I'm currently re-writing an app to use .NET MAUI (targets Windows and Android).

Part of the old version has a download routine which grabs anywhere up to 4Mb of data from a web service. I'm currently also rewriting the web service as well.

The download class looks like this

```
public class Download
{
     public List<CalloutsDownload> Callouts { get; set; }
     public List<StockLedger> StockLedger { get; set; }
     public List<ChargeCodeDiscounts> ChargeCodeDiscounts { get; set; }
     public List<ChargeCodePrices> ChargeCodePrices { get; set; }
     ...
     public List<StockCategories> StockCategories { get; set; }
}
```

The download currently grabs all of these - there are usually between 10 and 15 of these lists grabbed (hence the size of the data download)

I've reworked it so only the lists indicated as being populated (via a new API call) which cuts down the list for download.

My question here is two fold.

I'm planning on using `Task.WhenAll` with a pile of async calls to the web services and return from the calling method once complete. In theory this should be much faster than a single call that grabs the entire object.

From what I've read, I will need something like

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() => webService.Fetch("endpoint1"));
var t2 = Task.Run(() => webService.Fetch("endpoint2"));
var t3 = Task.Run(() => webService.Fetch("endpoint3"));
var tn = Task.Run(() => webService.Fetch("endpointn"));

 var done = await Task.WhenAll(new [] {t1, t2, t3, tn});
```

Is there a way in can create the list of which endpoints I need hit (essentially autogenerating `t1`...`tn` with the correct endpoint passed in) and then awaiting the generated list of endpoints?. LINQ used to have a `foreach` method but that was removed a while back but can be easily coded as an extension method but I'm not sure if that would improve things.

And the second part is will using `Task.WhenAll` going to be more efficient (time and processor wise) than single calls (so I have a different method to call each endpoint)?

Comment: _"I'm currently also rewriting the web service as well."_ - If so, you might want to consider switching to async API instead of doing Async-over-Sync.

Comment: _"Is there a way in can create the list of which endpoints I need hit (essentially autogenerating t1...tn with the correct endpoint passed in)"_

Do you have the endpoints in list form already?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` only awaits the already running tasks. Your code already runs multiple requests concurrently. If you have a list of URLs, you can use eg LINQ's Select to call an async method that returns a task, then await all tasks, eg `var tasks=urls.Select(url=>httpClient.GetStringAsync(url)); var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.

Comment: That said, you probably *don't* want to wait for all requests to end to process their results. And probably don't want to call 100 or 1000 endpoints at the same time. You can use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to execute process a limited number of endpoints at a time. You can create an asynchronous method that performs all the necessary calls and transformations and call it from inside `ForEachAsync`. A more advanced architecture would be to use Dataflow blocks like TransformBlock to break processing into concurrent steps